# Access to a attached volume to change permission

Tags: amazon-ec2

I've attached a volume to a running instance in order to change the owner of /var directory (I did the mistake of changing the owner of /var and lost the access to the instance).

Running cat /proc/partitions

```
major minor  #blocks  name

 202        1    8388608 xvda1
 202       80    8388608 xvdf
```

The var directory I want to change the owner is in "xvdf".

How I do it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to mount the filesystem on the volume in order to access the files:

```
mkdir /mnt/xvdf
mount /dev/xvdf /mnt/xvdf
```

Make the necessary changes in `/mnt/xvdf/var`, and then unmount it before detaching the volume:

```
umount /mnt/xvdf
```

Comment: I've done it but the file is empty...

Comment: @JuanCarlos What is empty? The `/mnt/xvdf` directory? Does `mount` show that it's mounted?